# How to display archive from one saturday next saturday range,Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress home page,  i am displaying the archives using the function

```
wp_get_archives('type=weekly&format=html')
```

and it outputs like

```
* July 19, 2010–July 25, 2010
* July 12, 2010–July 18, 2010
```

ie starting from monday to next monday.How can i change this from saturday to next saturday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the `start_of_week` option, which you can set under *Settings* > *General* > *Week Starts On*. If you don't want to change this, you could intercept the call to [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to return something different.

```
add_filter('pre_option_start_of_week', 'start_once_on_saturday');
function start_once_on_saturday()
{
   // Make sure we only do this once
   remove_filter('pre_option_start_of_week', 'start_once_on_saturday');
   return 6;
}
wp_get_archives('type=weekly&format=html');
```